# Phonegap: resource folder with content not visible in the apps /www/ folder, while available in the APK /www/ folder

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap

For a phonegap app we are developing we need some external files included in the assets/www folder (both android and iOS but for testing we are currently working with android).

The files are added to the www folder in the APK as seen in the screenshot below:
[image: Root folder with Javascript file that is included in the index.html]
[image: Contents of resources folder]

The ZoomAuthentication.js is included in the index.html of the www folder. As you can see when debugging the cordova app in Chrome, the ZoomAuthentication.js file is loaded properly, however, the other files in the *resources* folder which are imported in the ZoomAuthentication.js are not visible and throw a 404 not found in the console.

[image]

The following error is thrown by the debugger:
[image]

the ZoomAuthentication.js is a minified file, it fetches the file from the root directory of the app.

Comment: How are those files "imported in the ZoomAuthentication.js"? What does "are not visible" mean? Can you add a screenshot of how they "throw a 404 not found in the console." please? (Best answer all these questions by editing your question, then let me know here when done)

Comment: Hi Janpio, see the edit for some more detials. The ZoomAuthentication.js file is a minified file I got from a library, so I tried my best to figure out how the documents are fetched.

Comment: Can you please also add the correct network request for `ZoomAuthentication.js`? I currently don't understand the full file structure. Where is the second to last image with `top` from? Why doesn't that show a `resources` subfolder? Library is https://dev.zoomlogin.com/zoomsdk/#/web-guide I guess?

Comment: That is my whole problem :) the requests made from the file are the ones throwing the error in the last image, but the whole problem is, is that the resource folder is not showing up in the sources tab when I inspect my app with Chrome. While they are visible when I unpackage the .apk file.

Comment: Ok, so the second to last image is the "Sources" tab in Chrome. Can you please answer the other questions I asked? A great way to be able to debug this would be a new, plain Cordova app created with `cordova create` that only adds this code and demonstrates the problem. This should be easy enough to debug, but is really hard just with questions on a Stackoverflow question.